# Computing all the Haar-like features using scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, haar-classifier, viola-jones

How can we compute all the Haar-like features of all types using scikit-image function [haar_like_feature](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.haar_like_feature)? This is what I have tried (a simple example for computing all the features of type 2x):

```
from skimage.feature import haar_like_feature
from skimage.transform import integral_image

img = np.array([[1,  2],
                [1,  3]])

ii = integral_image(img)

features = haar_like_feature(ii, 0, 0, ii.shape[1], ii.shape[0], 'type-2-x')

print(features)
[1, 2]
```

However I would expect to get `[1, 2, 3]`, because we should also consider a rectangle feature covering the whole image resulting in the feature value `(2 + 3) - (1 + 1) = 3`.

I also checked the Viola-Jones paper and they have the following number of features:

```
type-2-x: 43200
type-2-y: 43200
type-3-x: 27600
type-3-y: 27600
type-4: 20736

total: 162336
```

(source: [An Analysis of the Viola-Jones Face Detection Algorithm](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/104/article.pdf))

However the number of features produced by `skimage.feature.haar_like_feature` is different:

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (24,24))
ii = integral_image(img)

total = 0
for feature_type in ['type-2-x', 'type-2-y', 'type-3-x', 'type-3-y', 'type-4']:
    features = haar_like_feature(ii, 0, 0, ii.shape[1], ii.shape[0], feature_type)
    print(f"{feature_type}: {len(features)}")
    total += len(features)
print("\ntotal:", total)
```

:

```
type-2-x: 43056
type-2-y: 43056
type-3-x: 27508
type-3-y: 27508
type-4: 20736

total: 161864
```

So it seems that there are 472 features missing in this computation. Am I doing it wrong? What parameters should I pass to the function `haar_like_feature()` to get all the features?

**Update**: there seems to be a bug in the implementation of the function `haar_like_feature`  https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4818

Answer (score -3):

for here,just wanna  share:

from here :
img = np.array([[1,  2],
[1,  3]])

to :
img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (12,12))

try to increase the input size of np.array() or image size..to for example 12x12.